# Is there a way to integrate A-Frame into Astro?

Tags: html, aframe, astrojs

I created a site with a 360-Degree background using [a-frame](https://aframe.io/). Since I want to do smooth transitions between different pages, I am trying to rewrite code within the Astro-Framework, but I'm having some difficulties.

Is there a way to use a-frame within astro?

The whole asto-filesystem is already set up, so i figured I could simply add the previous html inside of the `index.astro` file.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene xr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
                <a-sky id="backgroundRotation" src="public/space2.png" rotation ="0 0 0" transparent="enabled:true"></a-sky>
                <a-entity camera look-controls="enabled: false" wasd-controls="enabled: false"></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
</body>
```

But I was met with a loading screen. Nothing was happening.

I looked through the documentation and found a [guide on how to integrate other frameworks into Astro](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/#official-integrations). But A-frame was not listed as a official integration, so i searched further. On the a-frame documentation there was a guide on how to [install aframe with npm](https://aframe.io/docs/1.5.0/introduction/installation.html), so i tried this within the terminal:

```
npx astro add aframe
⚠ aframe is not an official Astro package. Use at your own risk!      
√ Continue? ... yes
✖ aframe doesn't appear to be an integration or an adapter. Find our official integrations at https://astro.build/integrations
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I found the solution to the problem on the [a-frame git](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/5254). Inside of the script tag there has to be an is:inline for some reason.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js" is:inline></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene xr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
                <a-sky id="backgroundRotation" src="public/space2.png" rotation ="0 0 0" transparent="enabled:true"></a-sky>
                <a-entity camera look-controls="enabled: false" wasd-controls="enabled: false"></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: `is:inline` can be used so Astro doesn't try to modify/optimize that script, you can read more here. https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#load-external-scripts